# Nuke the [android-gson] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I noticed there's now an [android-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson) tag. It doesn't have many questions yet and can easily be burninated, but I'm not a Java or Android guy and wanted to check with people who are, first.

As I understand it, there exists no Android-specific GSON library, and all that these [android-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson) questions are talking about is parsing JSON with the plain old GSON library in the context of an Android application. Is that correct?

If it is, we should burninate the tag (perhaps adding in the [gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) or [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tags to questions where they're actually key to the question). If not, it's worth somebody who understands what the tag represents giving it a decent description.

Comment: It has 574 questions now. Do you still feel we need to nuke?

Comment: @rene Yes; the tag still adds no information beyond what the combination of the `android` and `gson` tags would convey, and has an unclear excerpt that could be interpreted to mean that "GSON for Android" is a separate library. It adds no value and does harm, in other words - so it should cease to exist.

Comment: There are 48 question that are only tagged with [android-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson+-gson+-android). Maybe those need to be retagged so the tag can be removed without any further trouble (specially the questions where this is the only tag).

Comment: @rene yeah, the right resolution is to probably add the [gson] and [android] tags to all [android-gson] questions, then burninate [android-gson].

Comment: Since this has been status-declined, perhaps we should have a second request to merge [android-gson] with [gson] (since it refers to the same library)?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Why status-declined here? It's at +2 score with nobody having argued against it. Do mods mark burninate requests as status-declined just due to lack of interest?

Comment: @MarkAmery to be fair it also has a single down vote....

Comment: @rene Yes. But a single unexplained downvote doesn't strike me as conveying a community consensus against a proposal.

Comment: @MarkAmery As per [the burnination guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) - a proposal won't be featured unless the request has *atleast* a score of 20. Given this request has been sitting around for 3 years with little to no activity, I think it's fair to mark it declined

Comment: @Rob Well, yeah - it has 80 views. It takes [at least a few hundred views, and typically around 1000](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=160&sort=votes) for a Meta question to get to +20 score. It doesn't make much sense to me to equate "not enough people ever saw proposal for it to plausibly reach the vote threshold" with "the community rejected this proposal".

Comment: @MarkAmery there's been some confusion about what to do with it. I've removed the tag

Comment: @MarkAmery, I'd have probably marked it as [status-declined] too. Check out [plugging the holes in the burninate system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373599/plugging-the-holes-in-the-burninate-system). The issue is, we don't have a good way on meta to bring attention to old and forgotten burninate requests. Adding [status-declined] now, and then reposting the argument once it seems fit is probably a better way. (Luckily, it has now received an answer, thanks to the post being bumped by edits). If you have any other ideas to make the process smooth, please let me know, I'm all ears.

Comment: @BhargavRao Reposting the same argument seems likely to end up with duplicate closure, though. I'm not sure of the right solution either. However, one useful thing to do would be to add a link to the "plugging the holes" post to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/1709587 and note there that it's proper to use `status-declined` on a request that simply hasn't gained traction; I read the FAQ and its only mention of `status-declined` stated that *"This signals that the community decided against burnination of the tag"*, which is why I thought Yvette's use here was wrong.

Comment: Oh that's true. If we need to add that to the meta faq post (cc @rene), we probably also need to clarify about not closing the post as a dupe of older status-declined posts, in case the older post was declined because of lack of interest. Now, there's the related problem about how to differentiate between declined posts due to lack of interest, and declined posts because the argument to burninate the tag was not adequate. There certainly is a lot more planning needed for this.

Comment: @BhargavRao if I read my answer on the plugging the hole post I would still think this post needs to be status-declined but I've learned this is not only a matter of statistics but also of common sense. That is probably why the worksheet had tag:delete as suggestion. Let us think a bit if and how we merge what is covered in plugging the hole with the burnination FAQ. At a minimum we could start with a link so careful readers like Mark would probably have found it.

Comment: Cool @rene, I think we can discuss about that sometime next week (I'm moving to a different place this week, and therefore on mod vacation)? After that we can probably spend some time on converting most of the comment arguments on forgotten posts into answers (which probably would bump them), and later spend a day on declining the remaining requests, with a comment stating that they've been declined because of lack of interest (so that they're aware of why it was marked as declined).

Answer (score 14):

This is what I propose that we do:

The tag is obviously useless and it's also one of those dreaded combination tags that are destroying the tagging on Stack Overflow teaching users bad tagging habits.

However in itself the tag does not appear to attract off-topic questions. A normal [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071) process would force us to review all questions for (closing, edits) and this is probably a waste of resource considering the amount of other issues with only a handful of few brave users digging in them.

Instead, we ask/beg SE staff to execute the following update to not lose any current information.

1. Add [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag to all questions that have [android-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson) but not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) ([118 in number](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-gson%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0))
2. Add [gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) tag to all questions that have [android-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson) but not [gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) ([423 in number](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-gson%5D+-%5Bgson%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0))
3. Delete the [android-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson) tag!

Yes some evening fun for Shog9, 3 quick updates while we are slacking on the sofa.

Comment: I'm not sure if CMs have mass retag tools, but I've got another idea here. We can just manually add [android] tag for those 118 questions, and then merge [android-gson] to [gson], without creating a synonym, which will result in the same result.

Comment: @BhargavRao sounds like a plan if CMs can not execute these queries, but we would be bumping 118 questions which is why the other solution would be better

Comment: I'm not much worried about bumping 118 posts. They probably would stay on the main page for some 30 seconds. It is better to go through the easier route.

Comment: Ok let me know if CM will not do this, then I can try to gather a crew to start the editing

Comment: Shog9's evening fun activity was completed. (he has a mass retag tool :o ...)

Comment: Great! \o/ Thanks @Bhargav and Shog9 great mod and staff work!

Comment: I didn't do anything, it was Shog's work :p

Comment: @Bhargav, Well without your interest I'm not so sure it will have been done...

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not this burnination happens - by the hand of the community or [by the hand of Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379507/1709587) - I'm going to do the following more modest things tonight unless anybody talks me out of it:

- Edit the tag excerpt to say something like

  > DO NOT USE THIS TAG. There is no "Android GSON" library. If your question is about using the GSON library for Java in the context of an Android application, then separately tag it as 'gson' and 'android'.
- Manually eliminate the tag from the [top 30 posts using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson?sort=MostVotes&pagesize=30), tidying and retagging as appropriate, so they set a better example.

If you think I'd be wrong to do so - either because these are bad ideas in their own right, or because I'd be overstepping the bounds of what it's proper to do without a detailed community discussion - then please object in the comments on this answer.

UPDATE: Wiki is updated. I edited the top 16 questions, then stopped, because it was extremely boring.

Comment: @PetterFriberg what's the difference between `sort=votes` and `sort=MostVotes`? Aren't the search results linked to before and after your edit identical?

Comment: Signposts like this on tags are about as useful as the "9" key on a microwave.  It's there, it's going to be seen, but it'll be ignored come crunch time.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe. We'll see. I suspect the only reason the tag gets used is because it comes up as one of the only two results when you type `gson` into the tags box; I doubt anyone goes out of their way to type it. As such, I can imagine this going wildly differently to the typical case. But perhaps I'm wrong, and if we check the stats in 6 months you'll be vindicated.

Comment: Thanks for the six month offer, but [I don't need that long](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/973561).  Just have a think about that '9' key on your microwave...

Comment: @Makoto I don't understand that query or what I'm meant to infer from it.

Comment: @Makoto And in any case, I don't care at all whether people continue using the tag. Despite it being the first sentence of the excerpt, it doesn't matter. What matters is that the tag is clear that no "Android Gson" library exists, and that the previous implication to the contrary is removed. The sentences besides the second one are there purely because without them the reader would naturally wonder "wait, then why does this tag exist? When should I use it?".

Comment: @MarkAmery `sort=votes`, does not work for me, maybe only me, but if you like to test set a default setting as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson?sort=RecentActivity and then try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gson?sort=votes&pagesize=30